# Symfony 2.5 addViolationAt deprecated, use buildViolation()

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I have been following the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies) on how to create a class constraint validator and right now I am at the point where I am about to add the violation in the `validate()` function.

However my IDE notifies me the functions `addViolation()` and `addViolationAt()` are deprecated.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to use the [`Context\ExecutionContextInterface::buildViolation()`](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/Validator/Context/ExecutionContextInterface.html#method_buildViolation) function instead?

`$this->context` is an instance of [`Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext`](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Validator/ExecutionContext.html)

```
class ProtocolClassValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($protocol, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if ($protocol->getFoo() != $protocol->getBar()) {
            $this->context->addViolationAt(
                'foo',
                $constraint->message,
                array(),
                null
            );
        }
    }
}
```

When changing the call `$this->context->addViolationAt()` to simply `$this->context->buildViolation()`, I get the following Exception:

> UndefinedMethodException: Attempted to call method "buildViolation" on
>   class "Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext" in
>   *stripped path*
>   line 23. Did you mean to call: "addViolation"?

and line 23 has the following code:

```
    $builder = $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
    ->atPath('formField')
    ->addViolation();
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`addViolation` and `addViolationAt` are deprecated from 2.5 but won't be removed until 3.0 so they are still usable for a good time.

However... taken from the the [UPGRADE FROM 2.x to 3.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/symfony/symfony/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md) log...

The method `addViolationAt()` was removed. You should use `buildViolation()` instead:

Before:

```
$context->addViolationAt('property', 'The value {{ value }} is invalid.', array(
    '{{ value }}' => $invalidValue,
));
```

After:

```
$context->buildViolation('The value {{ value }} is invalid.')
    ->atPath('property')
    ->setParameter('{{ value }}', $invalidValue)
    ->addViolation();
));
```

With a bit more taken from [Context/ExecutionContextInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Context/ExecutionContextInterface.php)...

```
/**
 * Returns a builder for adding a violation with extended information.
 *
 * Call {@link ConstraintViolationBuilderInterface::addViolation()} to
 * add the violation when you're done with the configuration:
 *
 *     $context->buildViolation('Please enter a number between %min% and %max.')
 *         ->setParameter('%min%', 3)
 *         ->setParameter('%max%', 10)
 *         ->setTranslationDomain('number_validation')
 *         ->addViolation();
 *
 * @param string $message    The error message
 * @param array  $parameters The parameters substituted in the error message
 *
 * @return ConstraintViolationBuilderInterface The violation builder
 */
public function buildViolation($message, array $parameters = array());
```

Comment: I guess I was a bit too fast with accepting. Currently I'm experiencing the following error: UndefinedMethodException: Attempted to call method "buildViolation" on class "Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext"

Comment: I can only assume it's because the framework is still using the "old" context rather than 2.5+ version. The `@deprecation` is only a warning that it is to be removed in the future in the component, whereas the framework will be working at it's own pace I guess.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I added the following to the config.yml `framework.validation.api: 2.4` as a 'fix' for another problem I experienced earlier, which made me realize the problem is more an error on my end, than an issue with the framework. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to, sort of, help.