# Symfony 2 form conditional required field with fields not mapped to entity

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I have a form that requires field `conditionalRequiredField` only if `requireField` is selected.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add(
            'requireField', 'choice', array
            (
                'label' => ' ',
                'mapped' => false,
                'choices' => array
                (
                    'require' => 'Should I require that field?'
                ),
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true
            )
        )
        ->add(
            'conditionalRequiredField', 'text', array
            (
                'label' => 'I am required because the field above was selected',
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\SomeEntity',
            )
        )
```

...and some other fields, some of them mapped to entities.

The first field is not mapped to the entity. So in controller it's  not available when I access `$form->getData()`, it's only available through Request object. Now the question is, how and where should I add the validation to do it properly? To just validate whole form with use of `isValid()` method, without any additional logic in other places? I could probably put the validation in service somewhere, but it feels wrong. I've read a lot about constraints and validators, but they all seem to be connected with an entity field.

Thank you for your help :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine your entity linked to this FormType is call `MyEntity`

you probably should have somthing like that:

```
/**
 * @My\CustomValidation
 */
class MyEntity
{
    private $requiredField;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $conditionalRequiredField;
}
```

In order to create your custom validation, you can take a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator to create a class contraint validator

you validate method will looks like:

```
public function validate($entity, Constraint $constraint)
{
    if(!$entity instanceof MyEntity){
        return;
    }

    if($entity->getRequiredField() && $entity->getConditionalRequiredField() == null) {
        $this->context->addViolationAt('conditionalRequiredField', 'you.error.flag', array(), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :-). My main problem was that I didn't realize you can actually create a field in Entity that is NOT mapped to a database field. When you've showed me that, I've read so much about Constraints and Validators that when I had value from the form mapped to the entity property I could easily validate the form. Basically this solves my issue.

Comment: BTW PhpStorm "says" that addViolationAt is deprecated

Comment: Yes, i took this snippet from a Sf2.4 project, if you work with a Sf2.6, you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264922/symfony-2-5-addviolationat-deprecated-use-buildviolation

Comment: Yep that's what I used from the previous link you gave in the answer, thanks a lot again!